# Android users without cameras on their devices can't download my apps from Google Play - Why?

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

I have the following permission in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Is this the reason users without cameras on their devices can't download my apps from Google Play?

Is there a way to make this permission OPTIONAL? Meaning... I need to use your camera, but if you don't have one, you can still use my app anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the [Permissions that Imply Feature Requirements page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions-features) `CAMERA` implies `android.hardware.camera`. You can make it optional by including

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you! This should help me get on a lot more devices.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a [good article](http://schier.co/blog/2015/04/03/how-to-make-android-camera-permission-optional.html) which says what is in accepted answer but also adds information how to handle situation when user trys to open camera-related-feature but there is no camera.

Simple code from the article:

```
// Check that the device will let you use the camera
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

if (pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
    // Do camera stuff...
}
```